# Trouble with d3 force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm rendering a force directed graph using d3js. The design is such that nodes are added to the graph at run time by querying a database. This works fine.

While the graph is being rendered, node-by-node, if I happen to click anywhere on the screen, at sometimes, the incoming node gets stuck at the top left of the div and the following error is displayed on debugging:

```
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute x2="NaN"
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"
```

Sometimes, even an already formed link breaks and an old node gets stuck on the top left until the next refresh.

If I don't interfere, the rendering completes smoothly.

I really do not understand this behavior. Does anyone have any idea what must be going wrong here?

Find my code to compute the graph below:

```
var graph = { "nodes": [], "links": [] };
var nodeMap = [];
var timestamp;
var json_obj;
var newLogs = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;

    doPoll();

    function doPoll() {
        json_obj = "some object";
        var uri = 'api/values?id=' + json_obj;
        newLogs = false;

        $.getJSON(uri)
        .done(function doPoll(data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                newLogs = true;
                timestamp = item.timestamp;
                populateJson();

                function populateJson() {
                    if (nameExistsInNodes(item.entityName) && item.state == "1") {
                        searchAndRemoveFromGraph(item.entityName);
                    }

                    if (item.entityId != null && !idExistsInNodes(item.entityId)) {
                        graph.nodes.push({
                            "eId": item.entityId,
                            "name": item.entityName,
                            "state": item.state
                        });
                    } else if (item.state == "0" && item.entityId == null) {
                        graph.nodes.push({
                            "eId": item.entityName,
                            "name": item.entityName,
                            "state": item.state
                        });
                    } else if (idExistsInNodes(item.entityId)) {
                        updateEntityInfo(item);
                    }

                    if (!existsInMap(item.entityId) && item.entityId != null) {
                        nodeMap.push({ "id": item.entityId, "index": count++ });
                    }

                    if (item.mapsTo != null && !existsInLinks(findIndexForId(item.entityId), findIndexForId(item.mapsTo))
                        && findIndexForId(item.entityId) != null && findIndexForId(item.mapsTo) != null) {
                        graph.links.push({
                            "source": findIndexForId(item.entityId),
                            "target": findIndexForId(item.mapsTo)
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            if (newLogs) {
                renderUsingD3(graph);
            }
        }) // end done
        .always(function () { setTimeout(doPoll, 3000) })
    } // end doPoll
});
```

Each item that comes in has an id, name and state and my logic plays around with these 3 to get the graph up.

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Something that is calculating x and y positions is encountering `null`, which in turn yields `NaN`.